# Android java.lang.IllegalStateException database already closed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception

I have a really weird problem that i am not able to reproduce neither on emulator or on any of the tested android devices.

I have a SQlite Database controller that holds all of mine data access functions, in this class i have a simple function to check if a table exists:

```
public boolean tableExists(String tableName) {   
  if(db==null || !db.isOpen()) db =  dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();      
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='"+tableName+"'", null);
       if(cursor!=null) {
           if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
              cursor.close();
              return true;
             }
            cursor.close();
          }
      return false;  
    }
```

On my application start i create an async task to check for updates and on this process i will check for the existence of a local table in the database.

The error thrown is on the Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(... line, and the error is:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: database ... db.sqlite already closed**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.xxx.xxx.xxx.android/databases/db.sqlite already closed
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:59)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1364)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1332)
 at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.SQLiteController.tableExists(SQLiteController.java:1463)
```

I am not able to reproduce this error but according to ACRA this is happening several times in different devices.

Can someone give me a light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: ... since this code is in AsyncTask, check if it is not called twice (i mean two AsyncTask running concurrently)

Comment: Thanks, i have checked and it seems not. That could be a valid point as they could be recreated on orientation changes, but the specific async task is not triggered on prior orientation changes. So i'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Please put that second `cursor.close();` inside the else blocks follows

```
public boolean tableExists(String tableName) {   
  if(db==null || !db.isOpen()) db =  dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();      
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='"+tableName+"'", null);
       if(cursor!=null) {
           if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
              cursor.close();
              return true;
             }
          else{
                  cursor.close();
              }  
             }
      return false;  
    }
```

Comment: It does not seem to be the source of the problem. The error is on the rawQuery line.
And the else is executed if the cursor.getCount()>0 is not true: Correct, but that still happens on my code, if the if statement is true it returns true and the code is stopped, function exit. The cursor.close() will never be executed twice.

Comment: @Mojo could you tell us what for?

Comment: i posted for the scenario IF is succeeded, the the cursor will close inside, but again you're trying to close it;

Comment: yeah, sure Mojo ... after `return` statment ... did you take something ?

Comment: just check cursor.moveToFirst() condition after cursot not null exception, also try cursor.isBeforeFirst() condition;

Comment: its checking the count but doen't check its position ; pls try it dude:) you never know what mi8 come :P